# Selecting options from "selectize" drop-down menu selenium python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I'm trying to automate form filling and I'm running into an issue with Selenium. I have several drop down options that are coded differently than usual in HTML. Their class is "selectize-dropdown-content". I'm not able to select the options and have tried a lot of solutions which all failed. I added a screenshot in case anyone can help.

Thank you!
[HTML Code of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avXts.png)
[Drop-down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJuyR.png)

Comment: What url is it? Normal procedure concerning div tags are a click and then find the element which correspond to your element and click.

Comment: How would I find the element that corresponds to my element? I've tried so many things and it hasn't worked. Only thing I managed to do is click on the bar to display the options.
I tried choosing the other option through their xpath but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I'm assuming //div[@class='selectize-dropdown-content']//div[1] would work but I'd need more to test.